# Change Artifacts Explore Link in Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: azure-devops

I have successfully created a build within Visual Studio Team Services. One step of the build is to copy the outcome (artifact) to a `Drop Folder` which contains all versions of the artifact for that build. So far so good.

As you can see in the following image. I am using a `File share`  as the `Artifact Type` and then I specify the path where the artifact has to be copied.

[image: artifact configuration]

Now the issue. When I go to the build summary and click on the artifact tab, I can see the explore link. Clicking on that link will pop up the following:

> The browser cannot open the following location due to this browser's
>   security settings. You will need to copy the location and open it
>   manually.
>
> The location is: file://BuildServer/BuildDrops/MyArtifactName/[version
>   here]
>
> OK to copy the location to your clipboard.

So I set up an FTP server in such a way that the  `ftp://BuildServer/BuildDrops/` URL is pointing to the same path specified in the `Copy Publish Artifact` build task.

But I see no way to modify the link to use my custom URL.

Ideally, the `Copy Publish Artifact` task should accept a variable, let's say, `Artifact Link Base URL` so I can pass the value for the base URL and the link will use this value instead.

Anyway, my question.

Is there any way to modify the link whatsoever?

Answer (score 0):

There isn’t the way or feature to modify the artifact link URL in Visual Studio Team Services.

You can build a custom extension (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/overview_ to build a FTP URL according to build artifact download URL, then generate a hyperlink to navigate to corresponding FTP site.

Extension sample for build results: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-extension-samples/tree/master/build-results-enhancer